# EXCEL - Fuse text cells and split into different lines

Tags: excel, split, lines

I have a file that looks like this, containing a huge amount of data

```
>ENSMUSG00000020333|ENSMUST00000000145|Acsl6
AGCTCCAGGAGGGCCCGTCTCAGTCCGATGAACTTTGCAGCAATATTATAGTTATTCGTG
GTTCACAGAATTCCATTAAACATAAAGAAAAAACATAA
>ENSMUSG00000000001|ENSMUST00000000001|Gnai3
GAGGATGGCATAGTAAAAGCTATTACAGGGAGGAGTGTTGAGACCAGATGTCATCTACTG
CTCTGTAATCTAATGTTTAGGGCATATTGAAGTTGAGGTGCTGCCTTCCAGAACTTAAAC
```

the columns should be transformed so that lines always contain:

```
ENSMUSG***      ENSMUST***    GeneName     Sequence (four separate columns)
```

the Sequence column should be the lines starting with either A,C,G,or T fused into one text cell, the number of cells to fuse varies from gene to gene.

does anyone have advice how to solve this?

thank you so much for your help!
best wishes
kk

Comment: Data > Text To Columns > "|" separator

Comment: e.g., INPUT   A1 ">ENSMUSG00001 | ENSMUST00017 | Gnai3" ... A2 "AGATACAGCC" ... A3 "GTACATCTAC" ... A4 "CTATTCAAGCATAC" ... A5 "> ENSMUSG00002 | ENSMUST000023 | Asic2" ... etc. ...with text to columns or import feature "|" as separator ... OUTPUT ... A1 ">ENSMUSG00001" ... B1 "ENSMUST00017" .... C1 "Gnai3" ... D1 should now be =A2&A3&A4 .... number of cells containing the sequence parts is variable, can be between 2 and 10 ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Text to Columns` button on the `Data` tab. Choose `Delimited` , click `Next`, then select `Other` and in the box type the pipe symbol |. Then click `Next` and `Finish`.

Comment: This is good except one point, there does not appear to be a `|` between the Gene Name and the Sequence.  So a there will need to be another step to do the last split.  Maybe doing a second split on the new third column on the space if the name is always one word?

Comment: dear scott, thanks very much for your quick response... for seperating the first three columns this js of course easy... the problem is the sequence lines... to clarify... there are between 2 and 10 cells in column a that have to be fused and then inserted in column d... i know you can dise cells by =a2&a3& etc. but this should work in an automated way as there are more them 20'000 genes...

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is only those with Office 365 subscriptions that have the worksheet function `CONCAT`, which might be useful in this situation.  So I would do this with a VBA macro.

- First line -- split using the pipe `|` delimiter
- Then concatenate the next lines until we get to one that does not start with "A", "C", "G", "T"
- Store the results in a `Collection` object
- Write the results back to the worksheet.

Since you have a large database, the "work" is done in VBA arrays as this will process much more rapidly.

It is assumed that your data is in Column A, starting in A1; and that your results will be written in columns B:E

If your database is clean, and formatted as you show, it should work OK.  If it does not fall into the format you have presented, some error-checking might need to be added.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Organize()
    Dim COL As Collection
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim WS As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant, S As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

Set WS = ActiveSheet
With WS
    Set rRes = .Cells(1, 2)
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

Set COL = New Collection
For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
ReDim vRes(0 To 3)
    W = Split(vSrc(J, 1), "|")  'First line
    For I = 0 To 2
        vRes(I) = W(I)
    Next I

    S = ""

    'Concatenate subsequent lines
    'Could look for the "<" but OP gave specifice starting letters
    '  So will use that

    Do
        Select Case Left(vSrc(J + 1, 1), 1)
            Case "A", "C", "G", "T"
                S = S & vSrc(J + 1, 1)
            Case Else
                Exit Do
        End Select
        J = J + 1
    Loop Until J = UBound(vSrc, 1)

    vRes(3) = S
    COL.Add vRes
Next J

ReDim vRes(1 To COL.Count, 1 To 4)
I = 0
For Each W In COL
    I = I + 1
    For J = 1 To 4
        vRes(I, J) = W(J - 1)
    Next J
Next W

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

---